# #vote-differences link anchor seems broken in the Meta FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, hyperlinks, meta-faq

Mousing over the "What does voting mean here?" section of the [Meta Programmers FAQ](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) displays the correct link: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences.

However, clicking on it places `faq#dontask` into the address bar instead of `faq#vote-differences`. It does not refresh the page and put the quoted section at the top, but I'm not entirely sure if it's supposed to do that.

If I copy the link and paste it into the browser, it looks like both "dontask" and "vote-differences" sections are quoted at the top of the page:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some markup was missing here, it will be fixed in the next push.